# How to correctly use HOC with two kinds of props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm having trouble figuring out how to apply HOCs to this situation. I want to wrap existing components, since they all do very similar things. Here's a simplified version my current setup:

```
function CreateComponentHere(props: BaseProps): JSX.Element {
    return <ComponentWithComponentProps />;
}
export const NewComponent = withBaseProps<BaseProps>(CreateComponentHere);
```

-

```
export function withBaseProps<T extends BaseProps>(
WrappedComponent: ComponentType<ComponentProps>
) {
    return (props: T): JSX.Element => {
        return (
        <WrappedComponent componentprop={props.valueForComponentProp}/>
        );
    }
}
```

With this I finally have the `componentprop` pointing to the right type (`ComponentProps`) while the standard `props` are of type `BaseProps`.
However, right now typescript complains about:
`export const NewComponent = withBaseProps<BaseProps>(CreateComponentHere);` with the error:

> Argument of type '(props: BaseProps) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after discussing with a senior dev for a few hours it finally works and I understand what's going on. It turns out props and typescript in general don't work like I thought they did. 
The original props from the component I'm trying to wrap are also just sent through as props, and you need your types to reflect that. 
Also I apparently didn't need a generic here.

So the end result turned out like:

```
function CreateComponentHere(props: BaseProps): JSX.Element {
    return <ComponentWithComponentProps />;
}
export const NewComponent = withBaseProps(CreateComponentHere);
```

-

```
export function withBaseProps(
WrappedComponent: ComponentType<ComponentProps>
) {
    return (props: ComponentProps & BaseProps): JSX.Element => {
        return (
        <WrappedComponent componentprop={props.valueForComponentProp}/>
        );
    }
}
```